# Rouche's theorem for unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function $F(z)=2z^4+5.41z^3+10.24z^2+4.83z+1.414$.
And I need to prove how many roots does it have in unit circle, on unit circle and out of unit circle.
By Rouche's theorem I was able to prove that there are 2 roots in the unit circle by showing-
$g=10.24z^2+4.83z+1.414$ and $f=2z^4+5.41z^3$ on the unit circle g>f and because the coefficient $a_n$ of g is bigger then the sum of all the rest all his roots are in the unit circle.
Now I'm not sure how to do the rest. Any hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** The number of roots of $F(z)$ outside the unit circle can be connected with the number of roots of $$g(z)=z^4F(\frac{1}{z})=1.414z^4+4.83z^3+10.24z^2+5.41z+2$$ inside the unit circle.

Comment: Thanks, g(z) has 2 roots inside unit circle and because it is F(1/z) so what was out of the circle is now in the circle